# How should man pages be installed?

Tags: make, man

When distributing a custom utility I'll typically write a makefile that installs binaries to `/usr/local` by default

```
PREFIX ?= /usr/local
MANPREFIX ?= ${PREFIX}/man

install:
    install utility ${PREFIX}/bin/
    install utility.1 ${MANPREFIX}/man1/
```

The path to local binaries is fairly standard across different platforms, but the man path is not

- Linux: `/usr/local/share/man` or `/usr/local/man`
- MacOS - `/usr/local/share/man`
- BSD: `/usr/local/man`

Is there a portable way to write this makefile? It seems unreasonable to expect users to set MANPREFIX to the correct path before installing.

**EDIT:**

BSD make support assignment of a shell command using `!=`, which could be used to test if a path exists

```
SHARE != [ -d ${PREFIX}/share/man ] && echo /share || true
MANPREFIX ?= ${PREFIX}${SHARE}/man
```

This is a [new feature for GNU make](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-make@gnu.org/msg06382.html), so it's likely not portable yet. This works in GNU make, but not BSD make:

```
MANPREFIX ?= $(shell [ -d ${PREFIX}/share/man ] && echo ${PREFIX}/share/man || echo ${PREFIX}/man)
```

Answer (score 4):

The textbook answer is to use [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Installation-Directory-Variables). Finding the right installation directories on every platform is part of its job.

Autoconf isn't perfect, but it's often better than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What about utilities that require no compilation step, like a collection of scripts? Would you still suggest using a Makefile in that case?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran You may want to have an install target even if there's no build step, and you probably have test targets anyway. If you don't test, you might not have a makefile (or equivalent) at all and rely only on packaging-specific scripts (debian/rules, RPM specs, BSD ports, etc.).